# Where’s Wally’s secret location? (level 6)

Tags: google-maps

In this year April Fools' Google mini game, they did a "Where's Wally?" in Google Maps.

After beating the 5 levels, you are presented with a message of "secret level unlocked", where the following message displays:

[image: Wally. Unknown location. Find the next level. On the map, switch views to look towards the sky. Find Wally's avatar to see his new mysterious location.]

I tried switching to Satellite View and Street View, but I couldn't find any Wally's avatar.

Does somebody know where the hell is this guy?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Switch to satellite view, zoom all the way out until you see earth and a list of planets, switch to the moon, zoom in, and you will see him there

Comment: Great! For those who can't find the list: **close the Wally message, then zoom in and out again**.

Comment: I still can't zoom out. Google at its best I guess

Comment: @user2875404 [Try this direct link to the Moon](https://www.google.com/maps/@13.7164274,44.5037735,13954695a,44.9y,353.94h,0t/data=!3m2!1e3!6e2!4m4!7m3!1m1!1srs!2e2) (only works on Desktop)

Answer (score 32):

Depending on your version of Google Maps, you can find [Wally/Waldo](http://mentalfloss.com/article/22414/wheres-waldo-and-whos-wally)'s final location in one of two ways.

#### (Desktop) Visit the Moon while in Satellite View

Switch to Satellite View and zoom all the way out until a list of planets appears. Select the Moon and locate the Picard Crater, then tap Wally/Waldo.

If the planet list doesn’t appear, try using [this direct link](https://www.google.com/maps/@13.7164274,44.5037735,13954695a,44.9y,353.94h,0t/data=!3m2!1e3!6e2!4m4!7m3!1m1!1srs!2e2). (Only works on desktop)

[image: Waldo on the Moon]

#### (Mobile) Visit the Kennedy Space Center in Florida

Zoom out the map and head for the Kennedy Space Center in Florida, USA. Tap Wally/Waldo to launch into space.

[image: Waldo in Florida]

If you want to spoil *exactly* where Wally/Waldo and his friends are hiding on level 6, [refer to this answer guide](https://where-is-waldo-wally.deviantart.com/art/Where-s-Waldo-Now-Book-2-Scene-12-462401664).

Comment: It seems neither of these methods works on desktop

Comment: @Avery Method 1 works on Desktop. Waldo is on the moon by the Dorsa Harke. See my edited answer for a direct link.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I can't access the list of planets but the moon link works.

Comment: This is the better answer- provides both mobile and desktop instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Florida and it'll take you to the moon.

Comment: This worked for me, after California simply zoom out and go to Kennedy Space Center.

Answer (score -3):

you have to go out from Wally app to see the list of planets. It happens the same to me. Once you are in the moon you can find wally easily.